# Flick an element across the screen (HTML5/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create some "flick" like functionality. Instead of just dragging an item across the screen, I'd like to drag and throw/release it to a location. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Sorry I don't have any code snippets here...but I just don't know where to even start.

Thanks!
--moe

Comment: read [d&d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and use it for move `<div>`'s

Comment: https://github.com/tholman/cursor-effects I guess this is what SO used for their April Fool's day sprinkles which you could kind of 'fling around' by moving your cursor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event handlers to get the mouse events with the cursor positions at which they happened. You'd need to store the current cursor position (startCursorPos) and the element position (startElementPos) at mousedown. At each mousemove event, you can calculate the difference between the current cursor position and startCursorPos, and add the result to startElementPos, and use the result as new element position. This will implement a basic drag-and-drop behaviour.

To get the flinging, you need to also record the current time at mousedown and mouseup. Combined with the positions, you'll be able to calculate the movement speed, and use this at mouseup to continue the movement for some time (e.g. using setInterval).

```js
var foo=document.getElementById("foo");
var isMoving, startCursorPos, startElementPos, startTime, newPos;
function Point(x,y) {
  this.x=x; this.y=y;
}
Point.fromElement=function(el) {
  return new Point(parseInt(el.style.left), parseInt(el.style.top));
}
Point.sum = function(a,b) {
  return new Point(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y);
}
Point.difference = function(a,b) {
  return new Point(a.x-b.x, a.y-b.y);
}
Point.prototype.multiply = function(factor) {
  return new Point(this.x*factor, this.y*factor);
}
Point.prototype.distance = function() {
  return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
}
Point.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.x + "x" + this.y;
}
Point.prototype.moveElement = function(el) {
  el.style.left = this.x + "px"; el.style.top = this.y + "px";
}
foo.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  startCursorPos = new Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  startElementPos = Point.fromElement(foo);
  startTime = +new Date();
  isMoving=true;
},false);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (isMoving) {
    var cursorpos = new Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    newPos = Point.sum(startElementPos, Point.difference(cursorpos, startCursorPos));
    //console.log(startElementPos, cursorpos, newPos);
    newPos.moveElement(foo);
  }
},false);

window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  if (isMoving) {
    isMoving=false;
    var cursorpos = new Point(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    var interval = +new Date() - startTime;
    var movement = Point.difference(cursorpos, startCursorPos).multiply(1/interval);
    var speed = movement.distance();
    console.log(interval, speed, ""+movement);
    moveOn(newPos, movement, speed);
  }
},false);

function moveOn(startPos, movement, speed) {
  startPos = Point.sum(startPos, movement.multiply(speed*200))
  startPos.moveElement(foo);
  if (speed > 10) 
    setTimeout(function() {
      moveOn(startPos, movement, speed/2);
    }, 100);
}
```

```css
#foo { position:absolute; width:50px;height:50px; background:magenta; }
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="top:50px; left:50px;"></div>
```